# Scipy Find Peaks

Tags: computational-physics, visualization

I am trying to find the peaks. I have list `x_period` and `y_power`. I find the peaks from the `y_power` using `peaks,_ = find_peaks(y_power,height=0)`. But, when I tried to plot

```
plt.plot(x_period,y_power)
plt.plot(peaks,ypower[peaks],'x')
```

The peaks are not exactly on the peaks of the plot.
The image is : [image: Image of plot and peaks]

How can I show the peaks exactly on the plot of period vs power?? Any help would be great. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: This post is possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538028/finding-only-the-prominent-local-maxima-of-a-1d-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), `find_peaks` returns the *indices* of the peaks. But in your first plot command, the abscissas `x_period` have some data value.

Try

```
plt.plot(x_period[peaks],ypower[peaks],'x')
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how can I find the halfwidth for the highest peak    of above image ? I know `result_half = peak_widths(y_power,peaks,rel_height = 0.5)` Calculate half width and result_half[0] will give half width.

Comment: If the documentation isn’t clear, ask a follow-up question.